# Redirecionamento de paginas php

Tags: php

```
header('Location: leticia.php?id=1' .$usuario);
header('Location: barbara.php?id=2' .$usuario);
```

Estou tentando redirecionar 2 usuários logados, cada um para sua página usando o código acima, porém quando se loga, redireciona os 2 para a mesma pagina que é a da `leticia.php`, como corrigir?

Comment: Talvez fazendo um `if` verificando qual é o usuário logado?

Comment: Ainda não tentei ! Poderia escrever o código ?

Comment: Há alguma forma diferente de redirecionar ?

Comment: Não, você entende o que é o cabeçalho HTTP `Location`? Se não, seria bom pesquisar sobre para entender como funciona.

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisada .. poderia me ajudar com o código acima?

Comment: Recomendo voce redirecionar com javascript window.location = "arbara.php?id=2<?php echo $usuario; ?>"; o envio de cabecalho antes do html (DOCTYPE etc) seria a maneira correta http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php

Answer (score 1):

$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
if($resultado_usuario){
    $row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);
    if(password_verify($senha, $row_usuario['senha'])){
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row_usuario['id'];
        $_SESSION['nome'] = $row_usuario['nome'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row_usuario['email'];

```
    **header('Location: leticia.php?id=1' .$usuario);
    header('Location: barbara.php?id=2' .$usuario);**

}else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Login e senha incorreto!";
    header("Location: login.php");
} esse é meu codigo.
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça o seguinte:

```
if ($usuario == 1) {
    header('Location: leticia.php?id=1' .$usuario);
} else {
    header('Location: barbara.php?id=2' .$usuario);
}
```

Comment: Vou testar !!! Ronald.. vou precisar disso para 13 usuários como faço ? Desculpa a noobce kkk

Comment: Sinceramente não entendi muito bem o seu código. Pra mim, não faz muito sentido ter os nomes dos usuários em arquivos php (ronald.php, marcio.php, etc), mas já que esse é o seu cenário use um switch http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Não.. esses nomes são fictícios a página de cada um  não será esse  nome, resumindo preciso redirecionar os usuários do BD cada um para sua página .

Comment: Entendi. Então um switch resolve, creio eu.

Comment: <?php
switch ($usuario) {
    case 1
    header('Location: leticia.php?id=1' .$usuario);
    case 2:    
   header('Location: barbara.php?id=2' .$usuario);
}
?> Assim?

Comment: ...............

Comment: Algo nesses moldes. Vc não teria como colocar o código completo no pastebin?

Comment: Algo nesses moldes. Vc não teria como colocar o código completo no pastebin?

Comment: $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
if($resultado_usuario){
    $row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);
    if(password_verify($senha, $row_usuario['senha'])){
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row_usuario['id'];
        $_SESSION['nome'] = $row_usuario['nome'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row_usuario['email'];

        **header('Location: leticia.php?id=1' .$usuario);
        header('Location: barbara.php?id=2' .$usuario);**

    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Login e senha incorreto!";
        header("Location: login.php");
    } .. segue